# Referencing class methods and loading and iterating JSON in ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I am very new to ruby, but I need to learn it for a project that I am working on. I was given some skeleton code to start with that entails loading up a JSON in the form

```
def self.data
  path = 'data/spells.json'
  file = File.read(path)
  JSON.parse(file)
end
```

This a class method, and I keep trying to reference it in another method of the class, like

```
def names_with_same_first_letter
  spell_names = Array.new
  spells = data
  spells.each do |spell|
    if spell["Spell"].Lower
      spell_names.push(spell["Spell"].Lower)
    end
  end
  return spell_names
end
```

maybe it's just a syntax thing, but does this method return a JSON object?
I also tried doing self.data.each, and data.each but I keep getting a error

also, other methods use data just fine such as

```
def self.random
  new(data.sample)
end

def self.effects
  data.map{|el| el["Effect"]}
end
```

I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `data' for #<Spell:0x007ff04e81c130>
or
undefined method `data' for #<Spell:0x007fdd7323a1d8>
```

Comment: Where's `data` defined?

Comment: use `self.class.data` in your instance methods.

Comment: @SebastianPalma: first code snippet

Comment: Ayayay, I said nothing @Sergio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`names_with_same_first_letter` is an instance method in order to use class method `data`in it you have to use `self.class.data`

You can create class method for the class in two ways `def self.data` & `def ClassName.data` apart from this all the methods will be instance method.

to fix you problem change `spells = data` to `spells = self.class.data` in your instance method `names_with_same_first_letter`